# import com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.util.StringArray cannot be resolved at javac

Tags: java, ant

I am trying to write ant script for my project but at javac i am facing this issue:

```
80: package com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.util does not exist
[javac] import com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.util.StringArray;
[javac]                                        ^
```

JAVA_HOME is set to jdk1.6
ANT_HOME is set to apache-ant-1.8.4

build file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="project" default="war">
<property name="location" location="D:\Project"></property>
<property name="project-location" location="${location}\project"></property>
<path id="Web App Libraries.libraryclasspath">
 <fileset dir="${project-location}/web/WEB-INF/lib"/>
 </path>
    <path id="EAR Libraries.libraryclasspath"/>
    <path id="compile.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${project-location}/web/WEB-INF/classes"/>
        <path refid="Web App Libraries.libraryclasspath"/>
        <path refid="EAR Libraries.libraryclasspath"/>
</path>
<path id="Server Library [JBoss v4.2] (unbound).libraryclasspath"/>

<target name="init" >
    <mkdir dir="D:/JBOSSHOME/build/classes"/>
    <mkdir dir="D:/JBOSSHOME/dist" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init" >
    <javac destdir="D:/JBOSSHOME/build/classes" debug="true"       srcdir="${project-location}/src">
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>


<target name="war" depends="compile">
    <war destfile="D:/JBOSSHOME/project.war" webxml="${project-location}/web/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="${project-location}/web"/>
        <lib dir="${project-location}/web/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        <classes dir="D:/JBOSSHOME/build/classes"/>
    </war>
</target>
```

any help or pointer would be much appreciated ty!

Comment: Does the compile process finish successful, if you run javac without ant?

Comment: @reporter i didn't get you. (I am using ant as my classes are depending on multiple files and jars)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

com.sun.internal packages are NOT recommended to use , because

- they are not guaranteed to be available across environments
- support to those classes are also not guaranteed

Comment: after removing the import and using different data structure I was able to compile but still it is just a work around